# Google Cloud SDK Shell does not accept input - why?

Tags: shell, backend, gcloud, google-cloud-sdk

probably a stupid mistake: I am starting out learning about backend and am trying to deploy a google sample "app" to gcloud. 
I should be able to enter the command: "gcloud app deploy" after this screen.
[Picture of the Google Cloud SDK Shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADqbn.png)

But I cannot type anymore! The Shell will not do anything, when I type. 
It accepted the first two commands ("cd" and "dev_appserver.py app.yaml"). I can see the "hello world" on localhost. But then the little _ just blinks and I cannot do anything anymore.

Can you tell me why? I cannot find the solution on here or through Google.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Solution is "ctrl+break" the localhost first. One cannot have it running and deploy the app at the same time.